# Implied interest rate from FX swap

Tags: interest-rates, fx, forward

This is not homework. I am trying to calculate the implied interest rate of one currency (C2) using an FX swap and the interest rate of another currency (C1 - base). I have the following:

**Spot:** 7.7587 (C2 per unit C1)
**Buy Notional (spot) C1:** 12,888,757.14 
**Sell Notional (spot) C2:** 100,000,000.00

**Start date:** 6-May-13
**End date:** 7-May-14

**Buy Notional (forward) C2:** 100,000,000.00 
**Sell Notional (forward) C1:** 12,905,390,58 
**Forward FX rate**:  7.7487

I have a borrowing in C1 for 0.9650% for the year.
Using interest rate parity:
$$ F_0 = S_0 \frac{1+r_{C2}}{1+r_{C1}}  $$
I solve for $ r_{C2} = 0.8349\%$.
However, I am told that the right answer  is $0.8486\%$.
 Which should be the implied interest rate in currency C1. Am I crazy or missing something?

Do I need to consider FX basis?

**EDIT** 
If I use ACT/360 for C1 and ACT/365 for C2 with $ACT=365$ I get actually pretty close $(0.8483\%)$. Is that it? Is the difference caused by daycount?

C1 is USD 
C2 is HKD 
(I believe these are the correct day-count convention based on a paper by UBS). Not sure where to find the "official" declaration.

Comment: well, its impossible to say if you dont tell us which day count conventions must be applied. The question, wherever it is coming from should make a mention of that.

Comment: Apologies. I clarified the currencies in the edit.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because the day count of your inquired date is 366 days:

- Hkd daycount is act/365 therefore 366/365
- Usd daycount is act/360 therefore 366/360

$$
\frac{7.7487}{7.7587} = \frac{1+r_2(\frac{366}{365})}{1+0.00965×\frac{366}{360}}
$$

Solving for $r_2 = 0.8486$.

Comment: Awesome! How did you find out the conventions? Thanks.